# NSOperation will not cancel NSXMLParser. Which continues to call methods on delegate causing crash

Tags: delegates, nsxmlparser, nsoperation

I am trying to download some XML on another thread, and parse it.

I release the 'controller' then call cancelAllOperations on the NSOperationQueue.
And implement method 'cancel' on NSoperation which attempts to set nSXMLParser's delegate to nil.

But a second or so later the NSXMLParser is still alive and kicking and calls methods on it's delegate (which now no longer exists) causing a crash.

I just dont get it, what am I doing wrong?

```
#import "LoadXMLTheadedController.h"
#import "LoadXMLThreaded.h"


 @implementation LoadXMLTheadedController


- (id)initWithURLString:(NSString *)newString
{self = [super init]; 

queue  = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

loadXMLThreaded = [[LoadXMLThreaded alloc] initWithDelegate:self andXMLURLString:newString];

[queue addOperation:loadXMLThreaded];

return self;
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName     namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    NSLog(@" do some parsing.. ");

}


- (void)dealloc {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[queue cancelAllOperations];

[loadXMLThreaded release];
[queue release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end

//----------------------------------------------------------------//

#import "LoadXMLThreaded.h"

@implementation LoadXMLThreaded



- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)newDelegate andXMLURLString:(NSString *)newString
{
[super init];

delegate = newDelegate;
url = [[NSURL URLWithString:newString]retain];

return self;
}


- (void)cancel{

nSXMLParser.delegate = nil;
[nSXMLParser abortParsing];

 }
- (void)main {


nSXMLParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
nSXMLParser.delegate = delegate;
[nSXMLParser parse];    
}

 - (void)dealloc {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
nSXMLParser.delegate = nil;
[nSXMLParser abortParsing];
[nSXMLParser release];
[url release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you using the garbage collector or are you manually managing the memory?

Comment: I am managing the memory manually

Answer (score 0):

The NSOperation's cancel method simply sets a flag. It does not forcibly halt the NSOperation itself. The user is responsible for implementing the necessary code to stop whatever's running at the moment.

You would need to check periodically to see if the cancel flag is set, then call abort on NSXMLParser yourself.

Comment: When I cancel an NSOperation, do I have to call something like:  
`[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];`  
`_isExecuting=NO;`  
`[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];`  
`[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];`  
`_isFinished = YES;`  
`[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];`

Comment: Start a new question, and send me the link.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party with this one, but thought I'd put in my 2 cents.  Going off of @futureelite7, you should never override the `cancel` method.

Instead, throughout your NSOperation's subclass, you should periodically verify if the operation is cancelled by using `isCancelled` and act accordingly.  In this case, we want to abort the parsing.

For example, after your NSXMLParser delegate methods, make this the first line in the method:

```
// make your parser an ivar
if ([self isCancelled]) [operationParser abortParsing];
```

In addition, I recommend making your NSOperation the NSXMLParser delegate, so all parsing is encapsulated within your NSOperation subclass.

And lastly, just an fyi, aborting parsing will cause an error with code `NSXMLParserDelegateAbortedParseError`.  Just be aware of it during error handling.

Answer (score -1):

Apple's documentation:

> ### abortParsing
>
> Stops the parser object.
>
> `- (void)abortParsing`
>
> #### Discussion
>
> If you invoke this method,
>   the delegate, if it implements
>   `parser:parseErrorOccurred:`, is
>   informed of the cancelled parsing
>   operation.

I'm just guessing. Normally sending a method to `nil` isn't a problem in Objective-C. But maybe `NSXMLParser` does something fancy internally.

### General remarks about your code

- Learn how to write the [`init` method](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/the-how-and-why-of-cocoa-initializers.html) correctly.
- You don't have to set the delegate of an object to `nil` that is going to be deallocated anyway.

Comment: I am calling abortParsing in the method 'cancel' but it's not canceling, this is the problem.

Comment: regarding sending nil to delegate, I merely tried this in hope that it would stop NSXMLParser as abortParsing was failing to kill it.